# Counting Contacts with Events

Tags: soql, contact, event

I'm looking to count the number of contacts that have a certain event associated with them. I've come up with this formula, but it returns an error based on 'semi-joins'. I'd love some advice on this please! Many thanks

```
SELECT Id,Name
FROM Contact 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT WhoId from Event WHERE AppType = 'Stage 1 - HYBRID')
```

Comment: Please always include error messages verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

> 'Event' is not supported for semi join inner selects

So, you could execute 2 separate queries and find out the contacts like this:

```
List<Event> lstEvent = [SELECT WhoId from Event WHERE Who.Type = 'Contact' 
                        AND AppType = 'Stage 1 - HYBRID'];

Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Event evtObj:lstEvent)
{
    contactIds.add(evtObj.WhoId);
}                       
List<Contact> lstContact = [SELECT Id,Name
                            FROM Contact WHERE Id IN:contactIds];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error that you are getting is that Event is not allowed in inner select query.

You can just "switch" the queries, so that Event is in the outer

```
SELECT count_distinct(WhoId) 
FROM Event 
WHERE AppType = 'Stage 1 - HYBRID' 
AND WhoId IN (SELECT Id FROM Contact)
```

---

Let's review it line by line:

```
SELECT count_distinct(WhoId)
```

this will return the number of all unique `WhoId`

```
FROM Event
```

from Event object

```
WHERE AppType = 'Stage 1 - HYBRID'
```

for which `AppType` is equal to 'Stage 1 - HYBRID'

```
AND WhoId IN (SELECT Id FROM Contact)
```

and is linked to a Contact